# Reduce the complexity of matching the elements of two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, big-o, nested-loops

I wrote a code that extracts column headers (the first row in a sheet) from a google sheet and compares them with an array of objects. Each object in the objects array has 3 properties: "question", "answer", and "category". The code compares the header of each column, with the "question" property pf each object in the array.

If they're similar it should add the index of the column as a key to some dictionary and set its value to be an array that holds the answer and the category of that question. No need to much explain why I'm doing this, but briefly I built this logic to be able to grade applicants answers on some questions (hence linking the index of a question to its right answer and to its category). Here is the code:

```
 for (i = 0; i<columnHeaders[0].length; i++){
    for (j=0; j<questionsObjects.length; j++){
      //Get the current question and convert it to lower case
      question = questionsObjects[j].question.toString().toLowerCase(); 

      //Get column header, remove any spaces and new lines from it, and convert it to lower case
      columnHeader = columnHeaders[0][i].toString().toLowerCase();


      if (isStringSimilar(columnHeader, question)){

        //Link the column index to its corresponding question object
        var catAndAnswer = []; 
        catAndAnswer.push (questionsObjects[j].category.toLowerCase()); 
        catAndAnswer.push (questionsObjects[j].rightAnswer.toLowerCase()); 

        columnsQuestionsDictionary[i] = catAndAnswer; 
      } else {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("log").appendRow(["no", columnHeader, question]); 
      }
    }
  }
```

The code runs well, my only problem is complexity, it's very high. In some cases this method takes almost 6 minutes to execute (for this case I had around 40 columns and 7 question objects)! To decouple the nested loops, I thought of concatenating the questions values (of all objects in the questions object array) into 1 single string where I precede each question with its index in the objects array.

For example:

```
  var str = ""; 

  for (j=0; j<questionsObjects.length; j++){

    str = str + j + questionsObjects[j].question.toString.toLowerCase();

  }
```

Then, I can have another separate loop through the columns headers, extract each header into a string, then use regex `exec` method to match that header in the long questions string (str), and if it's found I would get its index in str, then subtract 1 from it to know its index in the objects array. However, it turned out that the complexity of matching a regular expression is O(N) where N is the length of the string we search in (str in this example), given that this will be inside the columns loop, I see that we still get a high complexity that can go to O(N^2).

How can I optimize those nested loops so the code runs in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: what is `isStringSimilar` doing?` why not move `columnHeader` to the outer loop?

Comment: @NinaScholz isStringSimilar compares the two strings, it tolerates up to 3 characters of mismatch. So, if the length difference between both strings is greater than 3 it returns false directly. If both strings are not null and not empty it uses 1 loop to iterate through both strings and compare characters at the same indices, if more than 3 mismatches are found it return false, else true. the used loop iterates N times, where N is the length of the longer String (so O(N)). As for moving columnHeader, I don't think that will reduce the complexity, will it? Thanks

Comment: in this case, you need to compare every header with every question ... moving `columnHeader` helps a bit, because it is only converted once and not n times of the columns.

Comment: @NinaScholz I see, you're right, that can help a bit. I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz your tip was really useful! I posted an answer to share the results with everyone.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I used the way suggested by **Nina Schholz** in the comments and I moved `columnHeader = columnHeaders[0][i].toString().toLowerCase();` to be in the outer loop instead of being in the inner one since it's only needed in the outer one.

The time needed to run the code was reduced from ~295 seconds to ~208 seconds, which is good.

I also tried switching the loops order where I made the outer loop to be the inner one and the inner one to be the outer one and updated the usage of i and j accordingly. I did that because it's always recommended to have the outer loop with less iterations and the inner one with more iterations (according to this [resource](https://hackernoon.com/neat-optimization-trick-reduce-the-number-of-jumps-in-a-nested-loop-a97fdbfd4c2b)), and in my case, the loop that iterates over questions object array is always expected to have number of iterations <= the other loop.

This is because if we want to calculate the complexity of 2 nested loops, it'll be (ixj) + i, where i and j represents the number of iterations of the outer and the inner loops, respectively. Switching the loops order won't impact the multiplication part (ixj) but it'll impact the addition part. So, it's always better to have the outer number of iterations smaller than the inner ones.

After doing this the final time of the run became ~202 seconds.

Of course since the loops are switched now, I moved this line to the inner loop: `columnHeader = columnHeaders[0][i].toString().toLowerCase();`, but at the same time I moved this `question = questionsObjects[j].question.toString().toLowerCase();` to be under the outer loop because it's only needed there.